# Format date as two digit month and day

Tags: apex, date, format

How do you set the .format() method to create a two digit month and day?

I have tried this

```
myDate.Format('dd/MM/YYYY')
```

The .format() method has no example of this on the support page. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Here is more of my code so you can see where I am using this:

```
For(Account_Servicing_Task__c tsk:accTasks){
            //Work through each frequency option.

            //Daily Tasks
            If (tsk.Task_Frequency__c == 'Daily'){
                For(Date d:Weekdays){
                    accActivities.add(new Account_Servicing_Activity__c(
                        Name                        = tsk.Name + ' - ' + d.Format('MM/dd'),
                        Account_Servicing_Task__c   = tsk.Id,
                        Status__c                   = 'Not Started',
                        User__c                     = tsk.Task_Assigned_To__c,
                        Due_Date__c                 = d,
                        Upon_Completion_Notify__c   = tsk.Upon_Completion_Notify__c
                    ));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only the `Datetime` type has a `format` method that lets you specify *what* format to use (instead of just the locale default). Likely that is because [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) supports many time components in addition to date values.

You would just use the month and day elements. For example, this format would yield `'03/22'` for today:

```
Datetime.now().format('MM/dd')
```

If you already have a `Date` instance and want to format it, instantiate a `Datetime` instance with it. I typically do something like:

```
Datetime.newInstance(myDate, Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0)).format('...')
```

Note if you're calling this code in a loop it may be better to just cache the formatted strings.

```
List<String> formattedWeekdays = new List<String>();
Time noon = Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0);
for (Date day : weekDays)
    formattedWeekdays.add(Datetime.newInstance(day, noon).format('MM/dd'));
```

Also, a piece of unsolicited advice: use more informative names. Using `d` instead of `day` saves you just two characters, and in my opinion is not worth the tradeoff of additional mental overhead.

Comment: still getting the error:  Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Format(String) from the type Date

Comment: I have added more of my source code to original post for you.

Comment: I already updated my answer to address your specific issue.

Comment: Format method is on DateTime accepts string where as formatMethod on Date doesnt